# Why is my Cross Product No Longer Working?

Tags: matlab

Cross product was working on my MATLAB, now it is no longer working. My partner and I moved our files to a totally different computer (where cross product was working), ran our scripts, and broke cross product on her computer as well.

Now, when I open up a fresh MATLAB session and type any cross products I get "Error using cross
Too many input arguments".

```
cross([1,1,1], [0,0,1])
```

This is the code that "broke" cross product, where eta, mu, delta are all numbers (and the inputs to cross products are column vectors of length 3):

```
p = (eta^2 * norm(cross(r_g_at_t1,r_g_at_t2),2)^2 ) / (mu*deltat^2);
```

I replaced the vectors with pre-made vectors A and B and that doesn't work. Oddly, dot product still works. I'm quite new to MATLAB so perhaps its a really simple thing..

Comment: Are the MATLAB versions the same on both computers? According to the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cross.html) `cross` was around before 2006a and still is.

Comment: You probably created a file called `cross.m` or a variable named `cross`. This causes the built-in function `cross` to be “shadowed”, no longer accessible.